# SUM and Group By in Ajax/MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I want to get the SUM of my Quantity column, and Group By the Location Name, using JSDataTables.

Currently the output gives me:

[image]

Which is fine, except when there are values in the table associated with the same Location.

Instead I would rather it display 'Unspecified Location - 25'.

I can achieve it on the database using query:

```
SELECT SL.StorageLocationName, SUM(LocalQtyOnHand) FROM tblStorageProduct SP
JOIN(SELECT StorageLocationID, StorageLocationName FROM tblStorageLocation) SL ON SL.StorageLocationID = SP.StorageLocationID
WHERE ProductID = 1
GROUP BY SL.StorageLocationName
```

[image]

Within my Product Controller I have the [HttpGet]:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetStorageProduct(int ProductID)
        {
            //Return a list of products in tblStorageProduct ensuring the levels are > 0
            IEnumerable<StorageProduct> objStorageProduct;
            objStorageProduct = _unitOfWork.StorageProduct.GetAll(includedProps:"StorageLocation,Product,Product.ProductStatus");
            objStorageProduct = objStorageProduct.Where(u => u.ProductID == ProductID).Where(l => l.LocalQtyOnHand > 0).ToList();
            return Json(new { data = objStorageProduct });
        }
```

Within my View I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var onHandTable = $('#tblStorageProduct').DataTable({
        "responsive": true,
        "ajax": { url: '/Product/GetStorageProduct?productID=' + @Model.Product.ProductID },
        "columns": [
            { data: 'storageLocation.storageLocationName', "width": "10%" },
            { data: 'localQtyOnHand', "width": "25%" }
        ]
    });
```

I have tried editing the HttpGet within the Controller to have a SUM(LocalQtyOnHand) and a GroupBy(StorageLocationName) but the Json response still returns 3 results and populates the jsDataTable with all 3.